# The Ferret Business: Moving a full stack at a time

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Is there any way to move a full stack through pipes and only a full stack? The reason is because I'm trying to automate my Fluxed Crystals setup. I have four gem cutters feeding into one gem refiner because the refiner just goes through items so much faster than the cutters can supply. My issue is that it gets stuck with 2 or 3 items left in the refiner, which isn't enough to make anything, and the cutters have moved on to other things. None of this would be an issue if I could move the stacks out of the cutters ONLY when they've chewed through a whole stack. If I could do that I could also move them INTO the cutters from my ender chest only when there's a full stack to ensure it won't ever get stuck.

I really need to automate this so I can have it growing a few different rare materials at once like bones, shiny metal, emeralds, etc. This wouldn't be an issue if I was only growing one thing at a time but that's resource heavy (initial investment of making that many seeds) and limits me to producing one resource at a time.

Comment: Are hoppers in FTB yet?

Comment: What sort of hoppers? The vanilla hopper is in, obviously. Could you clarify what you mean?